# beautifulsoup Extract text which doesn't have tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have HTML parsed text as below and trying to extract the texts in the same order.

```
<b>
 <i>
  Data
 </i>
 Data Summary
</b>
<br/>
Data Description
<br/>
<br/>
<pre>Data paragraph which contains huge string<br/></pre>
<br/>
<br/>
<pre></pre>
<br/>
<br/>
<b>
 <i>
  Data 2
 </i>
 Data 2 Summary
</b>
<br/>
Data 2 Description
<br/>
<br/>
<pre>Data 2 paragraph which contains huge string<br/></pre>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Am able to extract the between the tags `i` and `b` using `soup.findAll(['b', 'i'])` but am struggling to get the text without tags comes after every `b` tag. I have tried with `next_sibling` which doesn't even work with this. Any help would be appreciated.

The expected result is:

```
Data Summary : Data Description : Data paragraph which contains huge string newline Data 2 : Data 2 Summary : Data 2 Description : Data 2 paragraph which contains huge string
```

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Nope. I tried that but that returns the text of entire HTML page. Am looking to get text only for the above part and not for entire webpage.

Comment: What string specifically are you trying to find? "Data 2 Description" or something else?

Comment: Add the expected output in the question.

Comment: expected result `Data : Data Summary : Data Description : Data paragraph which contains huge string` newline `Data 2 : Data 2 Summary : Data 2 Description : Data 2 paragraph which contains huge string`

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make changes to your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all of the elements that contain text as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<b><i>Data</i>Data Summary</b><br/>
Data Description<br/>
<br/>
<pre>Data paragraph which contains huge string<br/></pre>
<br/>
<br/>
<pre></pre>
<br/>
<br/>

<b><i>Data 2</i>Data 2 Summary</b><br/>
Data 2 Description<br/>
<br/>
<pre>Data 2 paragraph which contains huge string<br/></pre>
<br/>
<br/>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
text_items = [t.strip() for t in soup.find_all(text=True) if len(t.strip())]
print(text_items)
```

This also strips any whitespace and only stores items that result in non empty strings. It would display the following list:

```
['Data', 'Data Summary', 'Data Description', 'Data paragraph which contains huge string', 'Data 2', 'Data 2 Summary', 'Data 2 Description', 'Data 2 paragraph which contains huge string']
```

Comment: I agree. But I have other lots of data which I don't want. I was able to extract the above mentioned section and looking the way to get data only from this section.

Comment: Usually there is a containing element that you would first `find()` and then carry out this code on that soup. Without seeing the whole HTML it is difficult to be more specific. Is there a URL you could give?